# Custom channel integration

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to integrate a custom channel (Custom developed community) that can be triggered from automation studio / journey builder. Content Builder templates should be used to send the actual content with personalization capabilities.

What are any concepts to get content pushed to the channel?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a custom activity.

I recommend you review the following : 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm

If you have a more specific question then please revise your question.